# user role permission query

Tags: sql

I have 5 tables: user > user_has_role > role > role_has_permission > permission

An user can have 0 or * roles.
And a role can have 0 or * permissions

now i have a query which will get all permissions belonging to a user.
This work but now i want that if the user has the role "super_admin" then all permissions get joined. But without specifing them in the table role_has_permission.

This is query:

```
SELECT        p.name,r.name role
FROM          user_has_role AS ur
JOIN          role AS r
ON            ur.role_id = r.id
JOIN          role_has_permission AS rp
ON            r.id = rp.role_id
LEFT JOIN     permission AS p
ON            rp.permission_id = p.id
WHERE         ur.user_id = [USER_ID]
```

Comment: " This work but now i want that if the user has the role "super_admin" then all permissions get joined", its confusing, can you please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a union:

```
SELECT        p.name,r.name role
FROM          user_has_role AS ur
JOIN          role AS r
ON            ur.role_id = r.id
JOIN          role_has_permission AS rp
ON            r.id = rp.role_id
LEFT JOIN     permission AS p
ON            rp.permission_id = p.id
WHERE         ur.user_id = [USER_ID]
UNION
   SELECT p.name, 'super_admin' 
   FROM permission 
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_has_role, role 
              WHERE ur.user_id = [USER_ID] and role.role_id = user_has_role.role_id and             
              role.name = 'super_admin')
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Dont know if this is the best solution but it works for now. I will do some more research later